# How: search results in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anybody  know how to meke the wordpress search results work just in a specific page template?
for example i created a page called Blog there's where i publish my articles. And i want when someone search for somthing the results appear just in my blog page.
Thanks..

i already tried this

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url('/blog/');?>"/>
<input type="text" class="searchfield" name="s" id="s" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" value="Buscar articulos...." />
</form>
```

But does not work

Answer (score 0):

Create a template called search.php and Wordpress will output the results using that template;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page